# Custom authentication for Skype for Business using SDK

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm following [this](https://ucwa.skype.com/reference/WebSDK/interfaces/_s4b_sdk_d_.jcafe.signinmanager.html#signin) link to implement Custom authentication.

I found out the following code in the same link:

```
sm.signIn({
    root: {
        user: 'https://lyncweb.company.com/.../user?originalDomain=company.com',
        xframe: 'https://lyncweb.company.com/.../XFrame.html'
    },
    auth: (request, sendRequest) => {
         // somehow get the token
        request.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ey...Az";
         // it returns a Promise, so the token could be
         // obtained asynchronously
        return sendRequest(request);
    }
});
```

There are no further explanation on what `user` and `xframe` in the above snippet.

**What we are trying:**

To pass the token of a user to the SDK in order to make the user sign in.
Is this approach possible ?

Comment: What approach are you using ? Are you using your organisation's server or Microsoft servers ?

Comment: We are using AZURE AD to host the app. 
We have the users auth token through OAuth , need to know if that can be passed through the above method.

Comment: user and xframe are the results from a successful autodiscover request (lyncdiscover.domain.com, etc).  The code above is short-circuiting both autodiscovery and authentication, but they have acquired the auth token from some other means.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do these. After you have authenticated with Azure AD and redirected back to your app, just use Skype.initialize. This would load the Skype Web SDK for your. After that, on success of this initialization, you can call sign In like you tried above in your code. But you have to use sign in using OAuth2. You can visit the same link you cited, and scroll to section **To sign in via the implicit OAuth2 flow specify the client_id**.

You can refer the link to [Set Skype Login using OAuth](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/03/skype-web-sdk-online-setting-everything-up-step-by-step-guide/)